# Ajax no se ejecuta correctamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo el siguiente código:

**Login_inicio.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fa-brands.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fa-regular.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fa-solid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header-login" class="card-header justify-content-center">
        <h1 class="text-center">Login Form</h1>
        <h3 class="text-center"><small>Bootstrap e ImageICon</small></h3>
    </header>
    <section id="login-inicio" class=" container text-center">
        <div class="row-form-inicio row justify-content-center">
            <div class="form-login-inicio col-6">   
                <div class="row bg-white titulo-login justify-content-center">
                    <h2 id="Titulo-login">Iniciar Sesión</h2>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group input-div-login-user">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="correo-usuario" id="correo-usuario" placeholder="Correo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-div-login-password">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password-login" id="password-login" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center btn-div-login">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn-login" id="btn-login" onclick="login()">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>              
        </div>          
    </section>  
    <footer id="footer-login">
        <div class="row row-footer justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <h3>Administración <small>2016-2018</small></h3>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax/ajaxlogin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajaxlogin.js**

```
function login(){
if ($('#correo-usuario').val()===""|| $('#password-login').val()==="") {
    alert("Hay campos vacios");

}else{

    var correo= $('#correo-usuario').val();
    var password =$('#password-login').val();
    alert(correo+" "+password)  

        ajaxLogin(correo,password)  ;
    }
}

function ajaxLogin(correo,password){
$.ajax({
url: 'php/consultas.php',
type: 'POST',
/*En el data se define los datos que se mandaran y como, en este ejemplo se envian los datos como tipo JSON*/
data: {Correo: correo, Password: password},
/*El beforSend se ejecuta hasta que se reciba una respuesta del servidor, mientras tanto mostrara el mensaje "Cargando..."*/
beforeSend: function(){
    //Hay que modificar esto
    document.getElementById('Titulo-login').innerHTML='Cargando...';    
}
})
/*Si la consulta se realizo con exito*/
.done(function(data) {
console.log("success");



})
/*Si la consulta Fallo*/
.fail(function() {
alert("Fallo");
})
}
```

**consultas.php**

```
<?php
sleep(3);
session_start();
include("bd/conexionbd.php");
$correo=$_POST['Correo'];
$contrasena=$_POST['Password'];

$cmd= $conn->prepare('SELECT CONCAT(empleados.nombre_empleado," ",empleados.apellido_paterno," ", empleados.apellido_materno) as NombreEmpleado, tipo_usuario.rol FROM tipo_usuario inner join usuarios on tipo_usuario.id_tipousuario=usuarios.id_tipo_usuario inner join empleados on usuarios.id_empleado=empleados.id_empleado inner join estado on empleados.id_estado=estado.id_estado where estado.estado=1 and correo=? and contraseña=?');
$cmd->bind_param('ss',$correo_usuario, $usuario_cont);
$correo_usuario=$correo;
$usuario_cont=$contrasena;
$cmd->execute();

/*Vinculamos las variables al resultado*/
$cmd->bind_result($user,$rol);
/*Almacenar el resultado*/
$cmd->store_result();
/*Se comprueba si hay resultados*/
if ($cmd->num_rows>0) {
/*Se obtienen los resultados guardados*/
$cmd->fetch();
//Seteamos el header de "content-type" como "JSON" para que jQuery lo reconozca como tal
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  /*Se llena el aray con los resultados*/
  $datos = array('Usuario' => $user, 'Rol' => $rol);
  /*Se crea el objeto JSON y se agregan los datos del Array*/
  echo json_encode($datos,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  /*Se crea la session*/
  $_SESSION['usuario']=$user;
}else{
echo 'no hay resultados';
}

?>
```

El problema es que el `ajax` no ejecuta el código php y siempre me muestra la leyenda ***fallo*** y después de revisarlo varias veces no encuentro el error.

Debuggeando me muestra el  siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta misma estructura la había utilizado en otros proyectos y no había tenido problemas.

Dentro de la función ajax puse un alert que sirviera de bandera y me muestra que los datos **correo** y **password** de la funcion `ajaxLogin` si se asignaron, el problema esta entre el data del ajax y el php consultas

Comment: Estás usando url limpias? de no ser así te falta la extensión del archivo url: 'php/consultas.php',

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Estaba haciendo pruebas y le quite la extensión para ver si arrojaba algún error, pero igual con la extensión que ya corregí sigue sin hacer nada

Comment: Entonces ejecuta y mira el network, te debe aparecer el archivo php le das click y ahí te dice el error en caso de que sea sintaxis o algo parecido

Comment: @CamiloVasquez según dice que tengo indefinidas las variables `Correo` y `Password`, pero anteriormente he usado la misma estructura y si pasa los datos.

Comment: @FernyCortez tengo que la sensación que su página se recarga verdad? no previene el `submit` del `form` _(no veo o se me pasó)_ , quizá deba agregar el `type` al botón `type="button"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que  está ocurriendo detrás de escenas y puede que sea su error es que el atributo `type` por defecto de los `button` es `submit` y no se está controlando dicho evento por lo cuál sí se envía el `form` con los valores de las cajas de texto pero con los nombres del form  es decir *(correo-usuario , password-login)* y no con `Correo` y `Password`.

Para solucionar puede `setear` el `type` a `button` en el botón

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="btn-login" id="btn-login" 
        onclick="login()"  type="button" >Iniciar Sesión</button>
```

Comment: Creo que en parte es eso, hice lo que me sugirió y ya no me muestra lo de fallo, solo se queda cargando y al debuggear, me sigue mandando que el correo y el password estan indefinidos

Comment: Creo que ya se soluciono, si era lo del `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando mandas los datos con la petición `AJAX`

> alert(correo+" "+password)

¿ Ese `alert` te muestra correctamente los datos tomados de tus `inputs` ?

Si te muestra correctamente los datos ese `alert`, creo que el error puede ser que te falta especificar el `datatype` en tu metodo `AJAX` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```html
function ajaxLogin(correo,password){
$.ajax({
url: 'php/consultas.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'JSON',
/*En el data se define los datos que se mandaran y como, en este ejemplo se envian los datos como tipo JSON*/
data: {Correo: correo, Password: password},
/*El beforSend se ejecuta hasta que se reciba una respuesta del servidor, mientras tanto mostrara el mensaje "Cargando..."*/
beforeSend: function(){
    //Hay que modificar esto
    document.getElementById('Titulo-login').innerHTML='Cargando...';    
}
})
/*Si la consulta se realizo con exito*/
.done(function(data) {
console.log("success");



})
/*Si la consulta Fallo*/
.fail(function() {
alert("Fallo");
},'json');
```

En caso de que el error persista, intenta en tu `PHP` establecer las 2 variables de correo y contrasena con datos de tu BD, y entras desde tu navegador haciendo referencia a ese `PHP` para ver que el error no este ahí.

Comment: Al principio creía que era eso, pero después recordé que ajax detecta los datos que estas utilizando, el problema estaba en el html, debia especificar el `type="button"`